# Wildfly 8.2 and SOAP web service - sending files over https

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap, wildfly

SERVER:
I have a SOAP Web service. Some of the methods of a web service handle receiving and saving files to db. The web service requires that it it called with a client-cert for authentication. The authentication is resolved by a custom login module.

```
@Stateless
@WebService
@MTOM(enabled = true)
@WebContext(authMethod = "CLIENT-CERT", secureWSDLAccess = false, 
transportGuarantee = "CONFIDENTIAL")
@RolesAllowed("meo_ws")
public class EDVWs implements IEDVWS
{
 ...
```

CLIENT:
I created a unit tests which call the WS. Before I secured the web service (HTTPS + client-cert) I was able to invoke all of its methods via tests. I then added the security and am still able to call the services that do not handle files. When I try to send the files to services, I get an 403 Forbidden error. I do not get that error for small files (less than 1MB).

Error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '403: Forbidden' when communicating with https://localhost:8443/Jedro-EDV/EDVWs
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1577)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1532)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:652)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
... 33 more
```

The weird thing is that if I add file to the call it is rejected even before it gets into login module. I tried to set max-post-size but with no luck.

```
<https-listener name="default-ssl" socket-binding="https"
                security-realm="SslRealm" max-post-size="52428800"/>
```

Client configuration:

```
public static void initServicePort(String endpoint, URL wsdlLocation)
{
    TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters = initTLSClientParameters();

    service = new EDVWsService(wsdlLocation);
    edvWs = service.getEDVWsPort();
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) edvWs;
    SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) bp.getBinding();
    binding.setMTOMEnabled(true);

    log.debug("Success!");

    configureClient(tlsClientParameters, ClientProxy.getClient(edvWs));
}

private static void configureClient(TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters, Client client)
{
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    http.setTlsClientParameters(tlsClientParameters);

    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(new Long(30000));
    httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(new Long(30000));
    http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any tip :)

Comment: Any solution to that problem?